# How can i create a Multi-Dimensional array as the following in php?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, sorting

Hi guys i am  trying to create a multi dimensional array as the format bellow but i am struggling to do so, any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
    $movies = array();
    $sql = "SELECT u.username AS Username, group_concat(v.title) AS Video_title, group_concat(r.rate) AS Rating
    FROM `rating` AS r 
    JOIN `uploads` AS v ON r.video_id = v.vid_id 
    JOIN `users` as u ON u.user_id = r.rater_id 
    GROUP by Username" ;

    $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    while($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
    $movies[] = $result;
    }

    foreach($movies as $k => $v){
    unset($movies[$k]);
    $movies[$v['Username']] = $v;
    }
    foreach($movies as $k => $v){
    unset($movies[$k]['Username']);
    }

    print_r($movies);
```

This is what i am currently getting:

```
     [user1] => Array ( [Video_title] => Snakes on the Plane,
                                         Superman Returns,
                                         The Night Listner,
                                         Lady in the Water,
                                         Just my Luck,
                                         You me and Dupree 
                         [Rating] => 3.5,
                                     3.5, 
                                     3,
                                     2.5,
                                     3,
                                     2.5 
                     ) )
```

But i am aiming to output it in the following format:

```
 'user1' => 
          array('Lady in the Water' => 2.5,
                'Snakes on a Plane' => 3.5, 
                'Just My Luck' => 3.0, 
                'Superman Returns' => 3.5,
                'You, Me and Dupree' => 2.5, 
                'The Night Listener' => 3.0
               )
```

Comment: your desired output is completely changed from what you get(in term of indexes or you can say column names). that's not possible

Comment: @AlivetoDie I dont really mean to have exactly the same output as in values only, but i am looking for alteration of number of arrays used.

Comment: M.Khalaf  check my answer once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do it like below:-

```
  $movies = array();
    $sql = "SELECT u.username AS Username, group_concat(v.title) AS Video_title, group_concat(r.rate) AS Rating
    FROM `rating` AS r 
    JOIN `uploads` AS v ON r.video_id = v.vid_id 
    JOIN `users` as u ON u.user_id = r.rater_id 
    GROUP by Username" ;
    $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    while($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
        $movies[] = $result;
    }

    $new_movies = array(); // a new array variable

    foreach($movies as $k => $v){
        $array_keys = explode(',',$v['Video_title']); // explode Video_title string into array
        $trimmed_array_key=array_map('trim',$array_keys); // trim all spaces from each value of $trimmed_array_key array
        $array_values = explode(',',$v['Rating']); // explode Rating array
        $trimmed_array_values=array_map('trim',$array_values);//remove all spaces from $trimmed_array_values array
        $new_movies[$v['Username']] = array_combine($trimmed_array_key,$trimmed_array_values); // combine $trimmed_array_key array and $trimmed_array_values array and assign to corresponding user
    }


    echo "<pre/>";print_r($new_movies); // print new array
```

Note:-

This line:-`$trimmed_array_key=array_map('trim',$array_keys);`

Will do something like below:-

https://eval.in/766605

reference:- http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php

Comment: Yeah i dont really know tbh, thanks anyways man i really appreciate your help.

Comment: @M.Khalaf  glad to help you. Please remove your previous comments. they are meaningless now.

Comment: My main purpose is to extract data in order to use it in this method: https://eval.in/766712 however its not working well is my problem a sorting problem or? this is what i get as an output https://eval.in/766713 Should i just change my question or update it? (errors are coming from line 4-6)(since its not recognizing the input)

Comment: @M.Khalaf  create a new question with all the details and different outputs and then someone will help you for-sure.

Answer (score 2):

Change the following line:

```
$movies[$v['Username']] = $v;
```

to

```
$movies[$v['Username']][] = $v;
```

and try again. It will create a new array under `Username` index for each iteration.

Comment: This is the output im getting: Array ( [Mohamed] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [Username] => Mohamed [Video_title] => Lady in the Water,Just my Luck,The Night Listner,Snakes on the Plane,Superman Returns,You me and Dupree [Rating] => 3,1.5,3,3.5,5,3.5 ) ) [user1] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [Username] => user1 [Video_title] => Snakes on the Plane,Superman Returns,The Night Listner,Lady in the Water,Just my Luck,You me and Dupree [Rating] => 3.5,3.5,3,2.5,3,2.5 ) ) ) Too many arrays on arrays

Comment: Your desired format is totally different then what you get.

Comment: What do you suggest i should improve on?

Comment: @M.Khalaf  check my answer and try it

Answer (score 1):

Try this code for your aiming result:

```
    $movies = array();
    $sql = "

    SELECT u.username AS Username, v.title AS Video_title, r.rate AS Rating
    FROM `rating` AS r 
    JOIN `uploads` AS v ON r.video_id = v.vid_id 
    JOIN `users` as u ON u.user_id = r.rater_id 
    GROUP by Username" ;

    $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    while($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
        $movies[$result['Username']][$result['Video_title']] = $result['Rating'];
    }

    print_r($movies);
```

Comment: Not quite there this is what i am getting now:  Array
(
    [Mohamed] => Array
        (
            [Lady in the Water,Just my Luck,The Night Listner,Snakes on the Plane,Superman Returns,You me and Dupree] => 3,1.5,3,3.5,5,3.5
        )

    [0] => 3,1.5,3,3.5,5,3.5
    [user1] => Array
        (
            [Snakes on the Plane,Superman Returns,The Night Listner,Lady in the Water,Just my Luck,You me and Dupree] => 3.5,3.5,3,2.5,3,2.5
        )

    [1] => 3.5,3.5,3,2.5,3,2.5
)

Comment: remove group concat from select query. and use this code.